# VBA not entering then statement

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement

This code is designed to look through a range of cells and compare their value with reference cells, then update certain cells based on which portion of the excel matches the reference values. I am getting an "invalid procedure call or argument" error. When I use F8 to walk through my code it seems to be triggered after the second If statement.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim rng As Range, cell As Range
  Set rng = Range("A171:AJ171")
  For Each cell In rng
    If cell.Value = ActiveSheet.Cells(4, 4).Value Then
      If ActiveSheet.Cells((cell.Row + 1), cell.Column).Value = ActiveSheet.Cells("D3").Value Then
        ActiveSheet.Cells("M45").Value = ActiveSheet.Cells((cell.Row + 3), cell.Column).Value
        ActiveSheet.Cells("M46").Value = ActiveSheet.Cells((cell.Row + 4), cell.Column).Value
        ActiveSheet.Cells("M47").Value = ActiveSheet.Cells((cell.Row + 5), cell.Column).Value
        ActiveSheet.Cells("M48").Value = ActiveSheet.Cells((cell.Row + 6), cell.Column).Value
        ActiveSheet.Cells("M49").Value = ActiveSheet.Cells((cell.Row + 7), cell.Column).Value
        ActiveSheet.Cells("M26").Value = ActiveSheet.Cells((cell.Row + 8), cell.Column).Value
        ActiveSheet.Cells("M27").Value = ActiveSheet.Cells((cell.Row + 9), cell.Column).Value
        ActiveSheet.Cells("M28").Value = ActiveSheet.Cells((cell.Row + 10), cell.Column).Value
        ActiveSheet.Cells("M57").Value = ActiveSheet.Cells((cell.Row + 11), cell.Column).Value
        ActiveSheet.Cells("M59").Value = ActiveSheet.Cells((cell.Row + 12), cell.Column).Value
        ActiveSheet.Cells("M60").Value = ActiveSheet.Cells((cell.Row + 13), cell.Column).Value
      End If
    End If
  Next
End Sub
```

Comment: you have an extra `(` in `If ActiveSheet.Cells((cell.Row + 1)`. You also have it in the assignment side of each line under that. Lastly, look into [With Blocks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/with-end-with-statement). You'll find it helpful here for faster and cleaner, more readable code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim rng As Range, cell As Range
    Dim i As Long
    Dim d4 As Variant, d3 As Variant
    d3 = Range("D3").Value
    d4 = Range("D4").Value
    ' rng starts at A171 
    Set rng = Range("A171")
    ' loop through 36 columns to AJ171
    For i = 1 To 36
        If rng.Cells(1, i).Value = d4 Then
            If rng.Cells(2, i).Value = d3 Then
                'Copy values from M45:M49 to Axxx3:Axxx7
                Range("M45").Resize(5, 1).Value = rng.Cells(3, i).Resize(5, 1).Value
                'Copy values from M26:M28 to Axxx8:Axxx10
                Range("M26").Resize(3, 1).Value = rng.Cells(8, i).Resize(3, 1).Value
                'Copy values from M57 to Axxx11
                Range("M57").Value = rng.Cells(11, i).Value
                'Copy values from M59:M60 to Axxx12:Axxx13
                Range("M59").Resize(2, 1).Value = rng.Cells(12, i).Resize(2, 1).Value
            End If
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Some notable changes:

- The value in `.Cells(4,4)` is the same as `.Range("D4")` and it is stored outside the loop in `d4`.
- The value in `.Range("D3")` is similarly stored outside the loop in `d3`.
- Use a `For` loop with index `i` so that you can reference cells in a table under `A171` with `rng.Cells(row,i)`
- Rear and write multiple contigious cells with the `Range(destination).Resize(n,m).Value = Range(source).Resize(n,m).Value` pattern.